# Python AES 128 CBC decrypt wrong result

Tags: python, cryptography

I do not understand why i don't get the same result with this python script and this bash command line:

python script:

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
import binascii

decryptor = AES.new("abcdef1234567890", AES.MODE_CBC,IV=binascii.unhexlify("a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1"))


data_crypte="1234123412341234"
clair = decryptor.decrypt(data_crypte)

f=open("output_file_py","wb")
f.write(clair)
f.close()
```

bash command line:

```
$ echo -n 1234123412341234 | openssl enc -aes-128-cbc -K $(echo -n 'abcdef1234567890' | xxd -p) -iv a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1 -nopad -out "output_file_enc" -d
```

Thanks

Comment: provide a [mcve] and that means providing sample values in and out that demonstrate the problem. Not `"32charlengthvalue"`. Provide short sample file data.

Comment: see my edit, i have added some data

Comment: Provide an example without a file, standard input and standard output with openssl and variables for python. This eliminates files from the problem and makes it easily testable.

Comment: Your bash command line tries to decrypt the input (by using the -d flag), while your python script tries to encrypt the input. Depending on what you are actually trying to do, change the appropriate code.

Comment: Sorry this is a mistake during redaction. I have changed, see my edit

Comment: @Bob5421 But now the both variants give exactly the same result.